# CSS change color of a div from within another div

Tags: html, css, html-lists

friends. I have two divs. In one div i have a few list items"li". What i want to do is every time i hover over the li in div 1, i want to change the background color of div 2. I need to use css for this. Thank you.

hello

so what i want is to change the background color of the div with the class "contents" to red when hovering over the li with the id "red". using css.
this is my entire Html file.

Comment: I misread your question at first- I can't see how this would be possible in CSS - there is no parent element. Can you edit your question to include any existing CSS. It is important,  for instance, if one of them if the first child in the list. Are you using LESS or SASS? Jquery or javascript would be the usual approach for many.

Answer (score 1):

in the case your `#childDiv` is **inside** the `#parentDiv`

```
#childDiv{
   color:gold; /* Default color */
}
#parentDiv:hover #childDiv{
   color:red;
}
```

otherwise **if your elements are not nested but in different places within your HTML** - you'll need a bit of JavaScript to accomplish what you need.

For starters I'd suggest to use jQuery, a JavaScript library. The code would look like this:

```js
jQuery(function($){

  $("[data-hover]").hover(function(){
      $("#"+ this.dataset.hover).toggleClass("bloodify");
  });
  
});
```

```css
.bloodify{
  background:#800000;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li data-hover=one>One</li>
  <li data-hover=two>Two</li>
</ul>

<div id=one>THIS IS DIV ONE</div>
<div id=two>THIS IS DIV TWO</div>
```